# Counting number of characters in a textarea

Tags: javascript

How can I count the number of characters (with spaces) in a textarea?
`textarea = document.getElementById("textarea").value`

I'm trying this `textarea.length` and `textarea.split(/./g).length` none works perfectly...

Comment: Have you tried to calculate value length?

Comment: @Suman that's not what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
alert($("#MyTextArea").val().length);
```

**Update1**

If you want to ignore lines in `textarea` for getting length then try this

```
alert($("#MyTextArea").val().replace(new RegExp('\n', 'gim') , '').length);
```

Using Javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementById("MyTextArea").value.replace(new RegExp('\n', 'gim') , '').length);
```

Comment: this worked. however I've simplified it to `.replace(/[\n]/g, "").length`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('textareaID').value.length
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery for this.

My code would look like this:

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function countChar(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
      $('#charNum').text(len);

  };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="field" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
    <div id="charNum"></div>
</body>
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/23kvP/)

Answer (score 0):

The below link might help you

http://curiositybeyondcontrol.blogspot.in/2011/10/count-number-of-characters-in-textarea.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Count</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function count(x)
{
document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML = x.value.length;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea onkeyup="count(this)"></textarea>
<span id="cnt"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("textarea").value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").length`